# type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

```
Map data={};
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     data=ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as Map;
```

Comment: Your argument is null. How do you send the data to this Widget?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if (ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments != null) {
      data = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as Map;
    }
```